ABP Pipeline fails with a lot of errors, even it works locally
I want to deploy ABP (asp.net boilerplate framework) by Volosoft for a new project. The ABP framework offers a robust foundational structure for developing modern web applications with modularity and best practices baked in.
I tried this:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    displayName: 'Build Job'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '8.0.302' # Specify the .NET SDK version

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '$(solution)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        projects: '$(solution)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: |
          **/*.HttpApi.Host.csproj
          **/*.Web.Public.csproj
          **/*.AuthServer.csproj

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        verbose: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy_HttpApi_Host
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployHttpApiHost
    displayName: 'Deploy HttpApi.Host'
    environment: 'Development' # Change this to your environment
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'AzureSubscriptionConnection'
              appType: 'webApp'
              appName: 'HttpApiHost20082024'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: '-WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE 1'

But I get a lot of errors:
https://btaste-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/hello_binarytaste_com/EYqP_JWB4mxJrC2mwUAcBOIBWcDD-DmYjP6aILKRo0-hJQ?e=vfPLhS
Locally it works fine

Include all of the relevant logs in your question, don't include a link to Sharepoint.

From the log you shared, it shows many Nuget packages errors like below:

error NU1101: Unable to find package Volo.Abp.Identity.Pro.Application.Contracts. No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg

The root cause of the issue is that the ABP packages are not exists in the Nuget.org resource, but they are existing in the ABP Commercial NuGet Source.
You can search for the packages in this site: ABP Packages
By default, dotnet restore task will only use the NugetOrg as the source. So it will cause the package not found error.
To solve this issue, you need to use Nuget.config file to your project. Then you can add the ABP Commercial NuGet Source  and NugetOrg source in the file.
For example:
Nuget.config sample:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="ABP Commercial NuGet Source" value="https://nuget.abp.io/{Your-Key}/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

When you use the dotnet restore task, you can use the nuget.config file to set the correct sources.
For example:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: Nuget.config

In the next build steps, you can add --no-restore argument to skip the dotnet restore steps.
For example:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'

